# How to update selected datetime64 values in a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I am trying to update selected datetime64 values in a pandas data frame using the loc method to select rows satisfying a condition. However, instead of assigning the new date-time value it results in NaT.

Here is a simplification of my code that shows the problem:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

datetime = (np.datetime64('1899-12-30'), np.datetime64('1989-12-30'), np.datetime64('2199-12-30'))

select = (0, 1, 0)

df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(datetime, select)),
                  columns=['date_time', 'select'])

# create a new column by subtracting 180 days
df['new_date'] = df['date_time'] - pd.Timedelta(180, unit='d')

# replace datetime with new date where select is true
df.loc[(df['select'] == 1), ['date_time']] = df.loc[(df['select'] == 1), ['new_date']]

print(df)
# the second element of the date_time column is "NaT", but this is not the desired outcome.
# the desired behaviour is for it to be the same as the second element in the new_date column.
```

I've also put the code here: http://tpcg.io/vOoi87Gb

Any ideas on how this should be done or why this is not working as intended?

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should drop `[]` around the column name:

```
df.loc[(df['select'] == 1), 'date_time'] = df.loc[(df['select'] == 1), 'new_date']
```

You can also drop the second boolean index:

```
df.loc[(df['select'] == 1), 'date_time'] = df['new_date']
```

Also, `np.where`:

```
df['date_time'] = np.where(df['select']==1, df['new_date'], df['date_time'])
```

**Explanation**: `df.loc[s, ['col_name']]` slices a **dataframe**, while `df.loc[s, 'col_name']` slices a series. When you do:

```
dataframe_slice = another_dataframe_slice
```

Pandas will try to align the index/columns of the two dataframe. In this case, the two slices have no common columns, so the updated dataframe has `NaN` values where `select==1`.